# How to make a responsive horizontal list

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to achieve a horizontal list and when the screen goes small the items become under each other, I explained that poorly, i want something like that what stack overflow has:
[image]

I tried some bootstrap4 but It doesn't seem it's working, when the screen goes smaller the list expands the document causing very bad mobile user experience, any solution?

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS that applies to this please, and also the container element for this list, as that might also need extra CSS to get this to work.

Comment: `li {display: block;}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
  .list-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1000px;
  }

  .list-group-item{
    min-width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
</ul>
```

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Is this what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I changed max-width to 100vw instead of 1000px and removed the .list-group-item class from the style sheet and it's now working exactly as i wanted, thanks for help

Comment: Shouldn;t this be `  .list-group-item{ max-width: 200px; }` not min-width? I am getting issues with

Answer (score 1):

Responsive list below 767px screen

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  color:blue;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  ul{
    width: 400px;
  }
  ul li {
    color: red;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it would be nice to avoid media queries, otherwise it works nicely